# How I can view the breakpoints from Slick before change?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I want the slider to "jump back" when the slider ends. The problem is that I have to do an individual function for each breakpoint. But the event "breakpoint" only give callback after resize the window.

Here is my code, maybe someone can help me.

```
slider.on('breakpoint', function (event, slick, breakpoint) {
  console.log("Breakpoint " + breakpoint);
  if (breakpoint <= 1400) {
    $(slider).on('afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
      console.log(currentSlide, slick.$slides.length);
      if (slick.$slides.length - 4 == currentSlide) {
        console.log("Last slide");
        jumpBack();
      }
      console.log(slick.slideCount);
    });
  } else { }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by `jump back`  , what do u want exactly

Comment: @aryanagarwal jumping from the last slide to the first one. But that works. The only big problem is the responsiveness.